# Override x-axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to override the x-axis tick marks, but nothing is being changed.  How do I change the x-axis so that it goes from 0 to 45?

Here is what I've tried:

```
library('ggplot2')
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(y = carat, x = price)) + 
geom_line() + 
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(seq(0:45)))
```

Also:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(y = carat, x = price)) + 
    geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:45, labels = seq(0,45))
```

[image]

Comment: second one works for me

Comment: Also note that if your labels are the same as your breaks, you don't need to specify them separately. So `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:45)` is equivalent to `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:45, labels = 0:45)`

Comment: Am I missing something? The lowest price is 326—they're diamonds!

Comment: @rawr When I run the second one, it looks like the `1:45` ticks show up where `1:45` actually are in the x axis values, whereas I think OP is looking for `1:45` spread across the x axis, i.e. scaled to the limits.

Comment: Perhaps? Is that what you're after? The `breaks` argument will set where the breaks go *in data coordinates*, so if you want evenly spaced breaks labeled 1:45 then use `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(diamonds$price), max(diamonds$price), length.out = 45), labels = 1:45)`

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `limits`: `ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(y = carat, x = price)) + geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:45, limits=c(0, 45))`.

Comment: @user164385 yes, good point, perchance. we may never know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for `0:45` to be scaled to the limits of the `x-axis` rather than bunched together where the actual x values 0 through 45 are, you can hack it together with a slight modification of your existing code:

```
xbreaks <- (0:45) * max(diamonds$price, na.rm = TRUE) / 45
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(y = carat, x = price)) + 
  geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = xbreaks, labels = seq(0,45))
```

This does exactly that: scales `0:45` to the limits of your data, then plots the sequence `0:45` of labels at the positions you just determined by scaling.

[image]